# Send SS7 SMS E1/T1 link

Tags: sms-gateway, ss7

I am trying to build a solution which can send SS7 SMS over E1/T1 link(Digium card). I found that asterisk can't send SS7 sms over E1/T1 link. I am searching for some open source which can send SMS over E1/T1 link. Can anyone knows about any open source solution by which I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you will *never* find the solution !
Have a look on that web page:

http://www.dialogic.com/webhelp/csp1010/8.4.1_ipn3/ccs_sccptcap_chap_-_introduction_to_sccp_tcap.htm

As far I know Asterisk SS7 only provides up to MPT3. You *have* to build software up to MAP, that is not present on picture, but next INAP. And that work is a big work, fully use less in 2017 because you can send SMS over IP by using SMPP. Have a look on picture, you have to build SCCP, TCAP, only to talk to SMSC, to use MAP protocol (you have to build), wit a test application that just send a SMS to the SMSC above that wall stacks of softwares !!!

What you are planning is a half (sending only) media gateway for SMS! This is a near by Telecom product mostly used to off-load SS7 network of SMS, if you are also able to receive SMS.

May be somewhere on earth, someone "made a hack", by by-passing that whole stack, because when you know the MAP protocols, traffic generation, it could be possible for someone ( a good dev, that I'm not) a do a special traffic generator just to send SMS.

The idea of the hack is to capture the complete exchange of SS7 messages (at MTP3 level) between an existing functional product that is able to send a SMS to THE particular SMSC you planned to use, and then to forge traffic with a C program running on SS7 asterisk stack, for each message captured for the sending. That "bullshit" SMSC client could work on one particular SMSC, but NOT with another SMSC from another constructor.

I'm afraid that could be the only goal you may reach in your plan. I'm sorry to tell you that. Doing with the "rules of arts" what you are asking is a big job.